# How to get filename without some special extensions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file that has some special extension. Sometime it is '.exe', or 'exe.gz' or 'exe.tar.gz'...I want to get the filename only. I am using the below code to get filename `abc` but it cannot work for all cases

```
import os
filename = 'abc.exe'
base = os.path.basename(filename)
print(os.path.splitext(base)[0])
filename = 'abc.exe.gz'
base = os.path.basename(filename)
print(os.path.splitext(base)[0])
```

Note that, I knew the list of extensions such as `['.exe','exe.gz','exe.tar.gz', '.gz']`

Comment: What about a file that is called `file.foo.exe`, should the result still be `file` or `file.foo`?

Comment: Should be `file.foo` because of the extension foo.exe does not contain in the extension list

Comment: did you find any of the answers satisfying ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just split with the `.` char and take the first element:

```
>>> filename = 'abc.exe'
>>> filename.split('.')[0]
'abc'

>>> filename = 'abc.exe.gz'
>>> filename.split('.')[0]
'abc'
```

Comment: what about `abc.tar.gz`

Comment: He said `file.foo.exe` should be `file`. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about a workaround like this?

```
suffixes = ['.exe','.exe.gz','.exe.tar.gz', '.gz']
def get_basename(filename):
    for suffix in suffixes:
        if filename.endswith(suffix):
            return filename[:-len(suffix)]
    return filename
```